# Checking in the database without any case sensitivity in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check in database without case sensitivity in controller.If it doesnot exists I want to save it, else I want to display Already exists notice. My controller is

```
def party_order_create
@party_order = PartyOrder.find_by(party_order_params)
if @party_order.present?
  flash[:success] = "Party Not Saved"
  redirect_to :action => "party_order_new"
else @party_order  = PartyOrder.new(party_order_params)
  @party_order.save
  flash[:success] = "Party Saved"
  redirect_to :action => "party_order_new"
end
```

end`

My model is,

```
validates_uniqueness_of :party_order_list, :case_sensitive => false
```

It works fine.. But I am getting party saved notice.. 
  Kindly please someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def party_order_create
    @party_order = PartyOrder.find_by(party_order_params)
    if @party_order.present?
       flash[:success] = "Party Not Saved"
       redirect_to :action => "party_order_new"
    else 
       @party_order  = PartyOrder.new(party_order_params)
       if @party_order.save
          flash[:success] = "Party Saved"
          redirect_to :action => "party_order_new"
       else
          // redirect_to 
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank You Sooo much @Dias.. I was trying in different ways.. This is soo simple.. Thank you